# How to query users by post count no less than 10

Tags: wp-query, users, query

I want to display 5 users by random who have published more than 10 posts but is not working. What I've done so far is

```
$args = array(
        'number' => 5 ,
        'meta_key' => 'post_count',
        'meta_value' => 10,
        'meta_compare' => '>',
        'orderby' => 'rand'
     );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
         echo  $user->display_name ;
     }
   } else {
              echo 'No users found.';
     }
```

I appreciate any help from you.

Comment: The meta query looks off, check e.g. how to construct the `meta_query` argument. In general random ordering and meta queries do not scale very well..

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your code you did mistakes with meta key arguments. You must use underscore instead of hyphen sign.
Here is corrected code:

```
$args = array(
            'number' => 5 ,
            'meta_key' => 'post_count',
            'meta_value' => 10,
            'meta_compare' => '>',
            'orderby' => 'rand'
            );

            $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

            if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
                foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {

                    echo  $user->display_name ;

                }
            } else {
                echo 'No users found.';
            }
```

Hope this will work!

Comment: Thx for the answer. When I changed to underscore, the output is _No users found._ . Why no results at all?

Comment: This did not work for me. No results at all for these query args.